Pyspark Streaming through socket into console but getting error
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = (
        SparkSession
        .builder
        .appName("Streaming")
        .master("local[*]")
        .getOrCreate()
    )

stream_df=spark.readStream.format("csv").schema("ID INT,Name STRING,Age INT,Department STRING").load("C://Users//Admin//PycharmProjects//spark-kafka//files//data1.csv")
stream_df.printSchema()
streaming_query = stream_df.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("csv").option("checkpointLocation", "C://Users//Admin//PycharmProjects//spark-kafka//checkpoint_loc").option("path", "C://Users//Admin//PycharmProjects//spark-kafka//output").start()
streaming_query.awaitTermination()

but after trying this I am getting this error :
ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = 28cd3601-e617-4554-92bf-65fafe708e4b, runId = d85c2785-74f1-460c-a515-050adbaad953] terminated with error
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'boolean org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(java.lang.String, int)'

pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.StreamingQueryException: [STREAM_FAILED] Query [id = 28cd3601-e617-4554-92bf-65fafe708e4b, runId = d85c2785-74f1-460c-a515-050adbaad953] terminated with exception: 
'boolean org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(java.lang.String, int)'

I tried reading local files for streaming still geting the same error. If I remove the "awaittermination" there is no error but the program finishes automatically without reading any data. I want to read data from kafka source after this code works properly.Please help I am new to pyspark.
